# Odds of playing the same artist twice in a row

Tags: probability

I have written a small program which takes a list of songs (say, 2000 songs), with varying amount of different artists.

Let's say I wrote a "song selector", which takes a set of 20 songs with the oldest "last played" timestamp. This selector will also only select distinct artists.

In this set of 20 songs that is returned, the same artist will never be in the same set of results more than once. (`SELECT DISTINCT artist, id FROM playlist ORDER BY last_played ASC LIMIT 20`)

This means the odds of any specific artist playing from this set of results is a 1 in 20 chance.

Suppose I choose a song randomly from the set of 20, and I get the artist "Elton John". Assume the next time a random set of songs is chosen, "Elton John" is in the result set again;

What are the odds the *same artist* would be chosen *twice in a row* by my algorithm?

Comment: Seem to be that this is at least going to depend on how many distinct artists there are.

Comment: @amd if so, I think a formula for figure out the answer would be ideal. The amount of distinct artists can change constantly